# An error occurred in the PHP script, MySQL error 2006: mysql server has gone away

Tags: php, mysql

my code imports data from *xml* to the database.

at some point in time, the code began to work slowly and I needed to optimize it. To speed up the execution of the script, I began to use multithreading. after using multithreading, I got an error

> MySQL error 2006 error: mysql server has gone away.

I began to change the `wait_timeout` and `innodb_log_file_size` server settings, but this did not solve the problem. Maybe someone came across this problem. What could be causing this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL error 2006: mysql server has gone away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942154/mysql-error-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away)

Comment: @Aman Rawat, thanks for the quick response. No, it didn't help to me.

Comment: There are several different `wait_timeout` settings (batch vs interactive, global vs session); you probably did not set the correct one.