# Connecting Laravel to XAMPP MySQL (MariaDB) database SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, xampp

I'm trying to set up Laravel 6 to connect to my XAMPP MySQL (MariaDB) database and I am receiving the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away (SQL: create table `migrations` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `migration` varchar(255) not null, `batch` int not null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("Packets out of order. Expected 0 received 1. Packet size=71")
      /Users/myname/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/htdocs/testSite/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70

  2   PDO::__construct("mysql:host=192.168.64.2;port=3306;dbname=testSite", "root", "", [])
      /Users/myname/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/htdocs/testSite/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70
```

My .env file has the following setup:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=192.168.64.2
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=testSite
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Comment: Restart your server and then run `php artisan serve`

Comment: It doesn't answer the question unfortunately, I did try this. It's not a matter of file size, as you can see from the question the size is only 71.

Comment: I still have the same problem after running `php artisan serve`. My XAMPP server is running fine so this shouldn't be the issue

Answer (score 0):

DB_HOST=**127.0.0.1**

You can do it like this should work fine.
just replace your IP with **localhost** or **127.0.0.1**.

Comment: I had already tried this, thanks for your suggestion. If I do this, then I get a different error "Connection refused"

Comment: connection refused maybe for different reasons.
say your database username and password issues.

have you checked username and password ?

Comment: Yeah I have checked the username and password, as well as the port details. The connection refused error is the same as if I use a random string as DB_HOST

Comment: Try reinstalling the XAMPP server after taking all the project and database backup.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942154/mysql-error-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away  refer this

Comment: Thanks, but it's not a max packet size issue, the size it's trying to send is only 71 bytes. I've already adjusted the max packet size and this has not fixed it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207259/discussion-between-anshuman-gupta-and-upsidedownb).

Answer (score 0):

The issue was a difference between versions of MySQL.

I reinstalled XAMPP and was able to resolve the issue.