# Error Number: HY000/2006, Codeigniter, Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making some simple queries in my little CMS but I'm receiving the error

> ## MySQL error HY000/2006: mysql server has gone away

I have two similar modules actually.

One of them, I get some text data from user and an image data. I'm uploading the image with verot.net class. Then I make a URI for that. Finally I'm inserting in 2 tables in my database.

First table stores the main data of content, the second table stores the lingual datas of the content.

In the second module I have an extra input: multi-file input. I upload my gallery files with verot.net too, then make the same process with previous module I told.

Then I get the error "MySQL server has gone away."

My `max_allowed_packet` is around 800 millions of bytes...

What causes this annoying this error?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942154/mysql-error-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away

Comment: I'm still trying many things and reading all articles, questions on stackoverflow but those are not solution for me... I'm still waiting for your answers...

Comment: There is nothing on this question that is any different from the linked question or from any of the other questions linked within the linked question. 

If you have researched things please **edit** your question and show what you've tried to fix this. Thanks