# How to Fix the MySQL Server Has Gone Away error in WordPress.And error established a database connection

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

When I update the WordPress website in the updated version. It shows the error on the Mysql. I use the MAMP server also tried XAMP but similar error. I changed into the php.ini file like upload_max_filesize=64M,post_max_size=64M and max_execution_time=30 but the issue is not solved.

[Mysql error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zigcn.jpg)

[PhpMyadmin error: This error show occurs when I import the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7x5u.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942154/mysql-error-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away Answer:https://stackoverflow.com/a/9479681/1593365

Answer (score 0):

you need to increase your max_execution_time time to atleast 300