# Drupal 8 |Mysql Gone Away Error when connection remote DB server

Tags: drupal-8, mysql-8.0

I am facing mysql gone away issue. Site was working fine past 2 days i am getting this issue.

I have tried all the combination max_allowed_packet , wait_timeout & Intractive_timeout still not working.

Tried with different Drupal instance in different servers & different DB servers same issue. Please help me to fix this issue. there is not network issue also ping , telnet working fine with 3306 port.

```
Additional uncaught exception thrown while handling exception.
Original
Drupal\Core\Database\DatabaseExceptionWrapper: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away: INSERT INTO {cache_discovery} (cid, expire, created, tags, checksum, data, serialized) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cid = VALUES(cid), expire = VALUES(expire), created = VALUES(created), tags = VALUES(tags), checksum = VALUES(checksum), data = VALUES(data), serialized = VALUES(serialized); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => entity_type [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => -1 [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => 1621427865.35 [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => entity_types [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 1 [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => a:8:{s:6:"action";O:42:"Drupal\Core\Config\Entity\ConfigEntityType":44:{s:16:"*config_prefix";N;s:15:"*static_cache";b:0;s:14:"*lookup_keys";a:1:{i:0;s:4:"uuid";}s:16:"*config_export";a:5:{i:0;s:2:"id";i:1;s:5:"label";i:2;s:4:"type";i:3;s:6:"plugin";i:4;s:13:"configuration";}s:21:"*mergedConfigExport";a:0:{}s:15:"*render_cache";b:1;s:19:"*persistent_cache";b:1;s:14:"*entity_keys";a:8:{s:2:"id";s:2:"id";s:5:"label";s:5:"label";s:8:"revision";s:0:"";s:6:"bundle";s:0:"";s:8:"langcode";s:8:"langcode";s:16:"default_langcode";s:16:"default_langcode";s:29:"revision_translation_affected";s:29:"revision_translation_affected";s:4:"uuid";s:4:"uuid";}s:5:"*id";s:6:"action";s:16:"*originalClass";s:27:"Drupal\system\Entity\Action";s:11:"*handlers";a:2:{s:6:"access";s:45:"Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityAccessControlHandler";s:7:"storage";s:45:"Drupal\Core\Config\Entity\ConfigEntityStorage";}s:19:"*admin_permission";s:18:"administer actions";s:25:"*permission_granularity";s:11:"entity_type";s:8:"*links";a:0:
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL error 2006: mysql server has gone away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942154/mysql-error-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away)

Comment: tried all still no luck.