# Python Flask App - MySQLdb.OperationalError: (2006, '')

Tags: python, mysql, flask, xampp, flask-mysql

I am trying to create an app for my clients.
I am using python, flask and xampp - mysql database, flask_mysqldb library for it.
I did import MySQL.

1. First client is going to register to app.
2. Then app is going to save client data to maindb
3. After that new database will be created and a new database user for it
4. That user is going to get all privilleges for the database just created

Mysql saves clients data on maindb, creates user but can not grant privilleges to that client.

When i use my app on localhost i get this error.
MySQLdb.OperationalError: (2006, '')

But this codes were working perfectly before i get some errors about xampp.
I handeled those errors. I tryed my app again and it is not working like before.

Now i want to share my codes. I got 3 files about this process.

1. main.py file

```
@gymsw.route("/register", methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    if request.method == "POST":
        return registeration(db)
    else:
        return render_template("register.html")
```

2. database.py file

```
class DataBase:
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app
        self.mysql = MySQL(self.app)

    def configure_db(self):
        self.app.config["MYSQL_HOST"] = "localhost"
        self.app.config["MYSQL_USER"] = "root"
        self.app.config["MYSQL_PASSWORD"] = ""
        self.app.config["MYSQL_CURSORCLASS"] = "DictCursor"
        self.app.config["MYSQL_DB"] = "maindb"
        self.mysql.init_app(self.app)
```

```
    def create_user(self, dbAdi, dbUser, dbPassword):
        self.cursor = self.mysql.connection.cursor()
        sorguForUser = f"CREATE USER '{dbUser}'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '{dbPassword}'"
        sorguForPrivileges = f"GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON {dbAdi}.* TO '{dbUser}'@'localhost'"
        self.cursor.execute(sorguForUser)
        self.mysql.connection.commit()
        self.cursor.execute(sorguForPrivileges)
        self.mysql.connection.commit()
        self.cursor.close()
```

3. utility.py file

```
def registeration(db):
    adSoyad = request.form.get("adSoyad")
    ePosta = request.form.get("ePosta")
    telefon = request.form.get("telefon")
    password = request.form.get("password")
    kulupAdi = request.form.get("kulup")
    aktivasyon = True
    dbAdi = createDbName(kulupAdi)
    dbUser = createDbUsername(ePosta)
    dbPassword = "mkrdmn"
    #Kullanıcıyı maindbusers veritabanına kayıt edelim.
    sorgu = "Insert Into users (adSoyad, ePosta, telefon, password, kulupAdi, aktivasyon, dbAdi, dbUser, dbPassword) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
    values = (adSoyad, ePosta, telefon, password, kulupAdi, aktivasyon, dbAdi, dbUser, dbPassword)
    db.exec_db(sorgu, values)
    db.create_db(dbAdi)
    db.create_user(dbAdi, dbUser, dbPassword)
    db.change_db(dbAdi)
    db.create_ogrenciler()
    db.create_gruplar()
    #kullanıcının okul adına göre veri tabanını oluşturalım.
    flash("Başarıyla Kayıt Oldunuz", "success")
    return redirect(url_for("index"))
```

When i get the error that i mentioned about it shows me the lines below. And they are connected ofcourse

1. this line in main.py

```
return registeration(db)
```

2)this line in utility.py

```
db.create_user(dbAdi, dbUser, dbPassword)
```

3. this line in database.py

```
self.cursor.execute(sorguForPrivileges)
```

I think the source of this error is step 3. But i do not know why. Because it was working perfectly before i reinstalled xampp.
Thanks for the people who can help me even.

Same code was working perfectly before i reinstalled the xampp.
I reinstalled it because with mssql server i can not run mysql on xampp.
I checked online, and they said some files were broken. Copy from mysql folder and paste those files to data folder in xampp.
I did it but this time mysql runs, but my databases were not working. So I reinstalled it and changed mysql port to 16000 so xampp will be the only application which uses port 3306. After all this, I got this issue.

Error Mesages

1. on browser - MySQLdb.OperationalError: (2006, '')
2. on visual stuido Code

   MySQLdb.OperationalError: (2006, '')
   127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2023 17:57:55] "GET /register?**debugger**=yes&cmd=resource&f=style.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -

   127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2023 17:57:55] "GET /register?**debugger**=yes&cmd=resource&f=debugger.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -

   127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2023 17:57:55] "GET /register?**debugger**=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -

   127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2023 17:57:55] "GET /register?**debugger**=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -

Comment: please post the complete error message

Comment: this is a timeout message try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942154/mysql-error-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried but it didn't work for me.

Comment: I think i fixed the issue. I wanna share it so anyone who has the same problem can see. I commented a line (self.mysql.connection.commit) and it worked.         self.cursor.execute(sorguForUser)
        #self.mysql.connection.commit() (this is the line i make comment)
        self.cursor.execute(sorguForPrivileges)
        self.mysql.connection.commit()

Comment: So please answer your question yourself and accept it

Answer (score 0):

I think i fixed the issue. I wanna share it so anyone who has the same problem can see. I commented a line `(self.mysql.connection.commit)` and it worked. `self.cursor.execute(sorguForUser) #self.mysql.connection.commit() (this is the line i make comment) self.cursor.execute(sorguForPrivileges)` `self.mysql.connection.commit()` –
mkrdmn